# Пересечение множеств

Tags: sql, mysql

Всем дня.
У меня вопрос в студию - как я могу получить пересечение множеств для таблицы с именем test:

```
+-------------+
| col1 | col2 |
+-------------+
|  1   |   1  |
|  1   |   2  |
|  1   |   3  |
|  1   |   4  |
|  1   |   5  |
|  1   |   6  |
|  2   |   7  |
|  3   |   12 |
|  4   |   9  |
|  4   |   1  |
|  4   |   2  |
|  5   |   11 |
|  6   |   30 |
|  7   |   2  |
|  8   |   1  |
+-------------+
```

Допустим, я говорю -- давай мне все пересечения для "col1 со значением 1" с остальными из столбца col1 на основе данных из столбца col2. Таким образом я должен получить все значения col1(кроме самого "col1 1") которые имеют схожие с "col1 1" значения в поле col2:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    ∩ 
2:(7) ∩ 3:(12) ∩ 4:(9,1,2) ∩ 5:(11) ∩ 6:(30) ∩ 7:(2) ∩ 8:(1)

в итоге, пересекаются всего 3 значения из 7 находящиеся в col1:

    4:(1,2)
    7:(2)
    8:(1)
```

В БД на выходе:

```
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
|  4   |
|  7   |
|  8   |
+------+
```

Мне нужны только первые 10 строк (но самые релевантные -- с самым большим количеством пересечений).
Желательно производительное решение, так как таких строк может быть от сотен тысяч до десятка миллионов.

Идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
SELECT t2.col1, COUNT(*) int_size, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.col2)
```

FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE t1.col1 = 1
AND t2.col1 != 1
GROUP BY t2.col1
ORDER BY int_size DESC
LIMIT 10

если кто-то готов предложить лучшее решение - я буду только рад

Comment: А так?

    select col1 from test t
     join (select col2 from test where col1 = 1) t1
       on t.col2 = t1.col2 and t.col1 <> 1
     group by col1 
     order by count(col1) desc 
     limit 10